# /etc/exports file not read on boot

Tags: linux, kubuntu, nfs

I added some entries into my `/etc/exports` file. But when I boot my system, the file is not read. I check it by `sudo exportfs` — it returns nothing (also I can't mount the exported folders on other systems).

Then I run `sudo exportfs -a` and then again `sudo exportfs` — and now all my exported folders are listed (and now I can mount the exported folders on other systems).

I'm running kubuntu 9.04 with 2.6.28-11-generic kernel

Comment: I spotted a bug in Jaunty that affects NFS mounts; seems the NFS client modules aren't getting loaded properly.  Is the `nfsd` module getting loaded properly?  Check after reboot, before you run the manual `exportfs` commands.  bug report: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/nfs-utils/+bug/117957

Comment: yeah, both `nfsd` and `exportfs` are listed as loaded modules

Answer (score 0):

Try running `/etc/init.d/nfs-kernel-server start` from the shell to see if it works; if it silently exits, try it again with

```
sh -x /etc/init.d/nfs-kernel-server start
```

to see where it's failing (missing executables or whatnot).